# Estoy intentando realizar una consulta select con where y no encuentra la columna

Tags: java

String user = texto5.getText();

```
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,username,password);
        



            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username  = " + user;
            
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while (result.next()){
                
                String name = result.getString(2);

                String pass = result.getString(3);

                String fullname = result.getString("fullname");

                String email = result.getString("email");
                
                texto1.setText(name);
                texto2.setText(pass);
                texto3.setText(fullname);
                texto4.setText(email);
            }
```

Disculparme, pero no entiendo el error, ya que no es sintactico, es que no encuentra la columna, y el username que selecciono realmente existe pero no lo encuentra, que ocurre.

Comment: Encontre la solucion, simplemente estaba correcto de  sintactica pero no de forma correcta, para poder mostrar la informacion. Se necesita de otro tipo de sitanxis para que jbc entienda la columna a buscar. en especifico este por si algien tiene la misma duda.   String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username  =  ?";
                
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                
                pstmt.setString(1, user);
                
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

Comment: guiaros por los ; para poder usar el codigo.